# Dynamically generating etcd discovery url with terraform

Tags: terraform, etcd

I have a terraform project that sets up a multi-node etcd cluster using etcd discovery url mechanism, with following setup:

main.tf (suppose to dynamically generate etcd discovery url and pass generated url as input variable to module below)

- etcd module

  - cloud-init sh script (receives discovery url variable and start etcd cluster nodes using this url)

The problem: I want to generate new etcd discovery url dynamically every time after running "terraform apply" (based on input variable, say numEtcdNodes) and pass generated url as variable to the cloud-init sh scripts in etcd module.

How can this be achieved?

I tried [this](http://maxenglander.com/2015/06/09/etcd-clusters-with-terraform.html) option: 
It doesn't work. The file interpolation method gets invoked first followed by generation of discovery url. So cloud-init sh scripts get old url used in previous run, so etcd cluster never comes up.

Comment: can you maybe set an explicit `depends_on` to ensure order of creation? see https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/dependencies.html#implicit-and-explicit-dependencies